# Can SQL filtering on azure service bus cause the messages to be delivered out of order?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

I have used a SQL filter on one of the subscriptions for a topic. I can see the messages coming in the subscription without any filter are in correct order but messages are being received out of order for the subscription which has SQL filter on it. To read the message I am using Azure SDK in Java. Is it possible that this is caused due to SQL filtering on messages?

Comment: Would you please post your snippet of key code? How do you bind the filter condition? what is your current result and what is your desired result? Please show more details?Thanks.

Comment: Following is an example of JSON messages which I am posting on the topic.
{
    "make": "ABC",
    "serialNumber": "XYZ",
    "version": 3
}
{
    "make": "ABC",
    "serialNumber": "UYZ",
    "version": 4
}
I am using SQL filter on one of the subscriptions of the topic as ItemsChanged LIKE '%serialNumber%. I am setting a header on message as ItemsChanged = serialNumber if there is any change in serial number. I should get the message with version3 first on the subscription because it was published to topic first but I am getting the message with version 4 first and then 3.